# Why is IF not returning a message?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I have a batch file, let's say it's named `batch_file.bat`. It contains the following content :

```bat
@echo off & @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set seconds_test=%1
set /a seconds_test=seconds_test +1
ping localhost -n !seconds_test! >nul
if !errorlevel! equ 1 echo Invalid seconds.
```

When I run it :

```bat
C:\Users\User\Desktop>batch_file.bat 3
```

It works and waits for 3 seconds. But when I run :

```bat
C:\Users\User\Desktop>batch_file.bat invalid_number
```

It doesn't return anything. My original idea was for this to return Invalid number. How and why does this happen?

Comment: Can you please provide context. I ask because `Set /A seconds_test=%~1+1 2>NUL` will only propagate an integer value, which means if it has any value at all, that must be valid. Also, I note that your used variable in the `ping` command doesn't match the name that you set above it, are you not supposed to be using `seconds_test` instead of `delay_seconds`?

Comment: Side note.  `timeout /t` might be your best friend.

Comment: Compo, Thanks, I got that error because the top part I wrote, while the bottom part I copied from the original file. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You do not need delayed expansion here since your code is not placed within a parenthesised block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If %1 isn't an integer, then `set /a seconds_test=seconds_test +1` will set seconds_test (or delay_seconds) to `1` because the rest of the set statement is thrown away due to the `/a` switch.

```
@echo off & @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set seconds_test=%1
set /a seconds_test=seconds_test +1
set seconds_test
```

`batch_file.bat a` returns:

```
seconds_test=1
```

Thus the ping command pings one time without error.
Here's how I would validate the input:

```
@echo off & @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:: check that something was entered
if "%~1"=="" (
   echo.
   echo You didn't enter any seconds
   echo Nothing to do, press any key to exit
   echo.
   pause >nul
   goto :eof
)

:: check for non-numbers in the input
echo %1|findstr /i /r "[^0-9]" >nul&&echo.&&echo %1 is not a valid number of seconds.&&echo.&&echo Press any key to exit . . .&&pause>nul&&goto :eof

set seconds_test=%1

:: check for leading zero
if "%seconds_test:~0,1%"=="0" (
   rem but zero by itself is ok
   if not "%seconds_test%"=="0" (
      echo.
      echo You entered %1.
      echo Please don't use leading zeros.
      echo.
      echo Press any key to exit
      echo.
      pause >nul
      goto :eof
   )
)

:: if we make it here, then the input should be an actual number.
set /a delay_seconds=seconds_test + 1
ping localhost -n !delay_seconds! >nul
```

There are a lot of things to pay attention to.  I use goto :eof where you might need exit.  I pause to display the errors where you might need execution to just continue.  I don't know that this is particularly elegant, or if there might be problems I have not considered/encountered.  @Compo might have better ways to validate the input.

Comment: You used delayed expansion but you didn't use it in the variables.

Comment: I just kept it there from the original code.  Never know if we're seeing all the code or just a snippet.